# Forbidden error when uploading files in centos server

Tags: php, jquery, file-upload, codeigniter-3

I'm using multipart/form-data to upload a spreadsheet and save it to my database. My code is working on my local machine but having an error once I uploaded it to my centos server.

```
  <form role="form" action="<?php echo base_url('importer/import_spreadsheet') ?>" method="post" id="uploadForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="modal-body">

      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="file" name="uploadfile" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Name" id="uploadfile" accept=".xls, .xlsx" required>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </form>
```

Jquery:

```
$("#uploadForm").unbind('submit').on('submit', function() {
      var form = $(this);

      $.ajax({
        url: form.attr('action'),
        type: form.attr('method'),
        data: new FormData(this),
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response) {
          console.log(response);
        }
      });
      return false;
    });
```

Controller

```
$upload_file = $_FILES['uploadfile']['name'];
$extension = pathinfo($upload_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

if ($extension == 'csv') {
    $reader = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Csv();
} else if ($extension == 'xls') {
    $reader = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Xls();
} else {
    $reader = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Xlsx();
}

$spreadsheet = $reader->load($_FILES['uploadfile']['tmp_name']);
```

It returns forbidden and these are the errors

```
Message: Undefined index: uploadfile
```

Also `$_FILES` is empty when you print it in the controller

UPDATE:
Removed underscore in upload_file

Comment: Does it work if you submit the form normally, not using AJAX? Have you checked what the error log has to say?

Comment: @CBroe actually I don't know how to do it without using AJAX. And I'm creating insert logs to be returned from the controller. I think this is not actually uploading the file to be saved. I'm just looping through .xlsx and saving it directly to database. Its working in my windows localhost using xampp. But when I push it to a centos 7 server, $_FILES becomes null.

Comment: _"I don't know how to do it without using AJAX"_ - by removing the JavaScript that binds the submit handler ...? And what about the error log, have you checked what it has to say yet?

Comment: @CBroe I mean I don't know how to handle controller response without using AJAX. Btw the same 403 Forbidden error. And when using Ajax `Message: Undefined index: uploadfile` because of null $_FILES.